# How to fix UI of GMSAutocompleteViewController in iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, google-places

Before iOS 15, the Autocomplete feature was totally fine. However, from iOS 15, the GMSAutocompleteViewController has the bug as can be seen in the following screenshot. The screenshot also shows the codes for GMSAutocompleteViewController.


At first I thought it was because I used the old version of the Google Places SDK since it has not been upgraded for 2 years. However, after I upgraded the SDK to the latest version, which is 6.1.1, the bug is still there.


I would like to ask for how to fix it?


[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can't find a direct solution on Google.

I found a workaround solution in the [here](https://mobikul.com/google-place-autocomplete-picker-integration-in-ios-swift/).

The solution is to implement an autocomplete view controller using `GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController` and `UISearchController`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).